# Thumbnails not showing Pictures

Tags: filemanager, thumbnails

[image: File Manager]

This is Ubuntu 14.04. I have connected my phone (One Plus).

Instead of the thumbnails like these "with JPG written on black background", I want actual thumbnails with pictures.

Comment: please remove and re-attach the device...

Comment: Have tried that before. Doesn't work.